# Check if current date and time falls within a date range excluding weekends

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, intervals, dayofweek

I am writing a project which handles card reading for door passing. The system must check if the swiped card has permission to a specific door at that specific time. For example, some cards do not have permission during weekends or outside working hours which are 8-20. How do I program such a thing with Joda-Time?

Right now I have:

```
//The code below that I have only checks for within a given date and time range.
DateTime start = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31, 0, 0);
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
boolean DateTimeCheck3 = interval.contains(time); // time is predeclared and gets current time from another class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `1 <= time.getDayOfWeek() && time.getDayOfWeek() <= 5` You can ensure that the day of the week is between Monday `1` and Friday `5`.